# split triangles on overlap

Tags: geometry, 2d

I have a triangle (red, below).   *(or a 2D mesh of triangles)*

How can I compute the polygons (and in turn tessellate them) that result from subtracting a second triangle (green) from the first?

[image]

(I'm using Python and I'm looking for an explanation and pseudo-code of an approach I can take, rather than recommendations for opaque libraries.  (I currently use [`gluTess*()`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluTessBeginPolygon.3G.xml) to do the tessellation of polygons, but an explanation of how to do the tesselltation myself would be interesting; my pressing problem is really the Boolean operation itself though.)   It will be exciting to learn and understand the solution.  My triangles are always counter-clockwise winding, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Your sample diagram shows a simple case. But what if one of the green triangle's points is **inside** the red one? Or it is completely enclosed within the red triangle? Then it can get tricky.

Comment: Absolutely it gets really tricky really quickly!  Hence asking for help here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through some scenarios...

**Case 1**: Triangles do not overlap (or they are tangent but not overlapping)
[image: Case 1]

Test for this case by using a [point-in-polygon algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) to see if any of the three vertices of one of the triangles lies inside of or on the other.

If we are in Case 1, we don't need to do anything.

**Case 2**: Green triangle is inside of red triangle.

[image: Case 2]

Test for this case by either using a point-in-polygon algorithm to see if all three of the green vertices are inside of the red triangle.  Another way to test this is to see if any of the 3 line segments of the green triangle intersect with any of the 3 line segments of the red triangle;  use an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection) like this for intersection (additionally you have to also check to make sure at least one green vertex in inside the polygon - just to make sure your lack of intersecting lines isn't because you are actually running into Case 1).

Now for this case, draw a line segment from each of the green vertices to each of the red vertices (total of 9 new line segments).  If any of these new line segments cross into the green triangle then remove them (you can check for this by using the line segment intersection method against each of the green triangle's sides).  Now, test to see if any of the remaining new line segments intersect with each other; if any two do, then eliminate one, and retest until you have no more new line segments intersecting with each other.

[image: Case 2 - Solving]

**Case 3**: Green triangle overlaps red triangle, where two sides of the green triangle enter into the red triangle and also leave the red triangle.

[image: Case 3]

Test for this case by checking to see that exactly two green sides each intersect with two red sides.  Again use the line segment intersection algorithm.

Now for this case, draw a line segment from each of the intersection points (each place where a green side intersects with a red side) to each of the red vertices.  If any of these line segments basically duplicate the red edges then remove them.  If any of these new line segments cross into the green triangle then remove them (you can check for this by using the line segment intersection method against each of the green triangle's sides).  Now, test to see if any of the remaining new line segments intersect with each other; if any two do, then eliminate one, and retest until you have no more new line segments intersecting with each other.

[image: Case 3 - Solving]

**Case 4**: Green triangle overlaps red triangle, where two sides of the green triangle enter into the red triangle but they do not leave the red triangle out another side.

[image: Case 4]

Test for this case by checking to see that exactly two green sides each intersect with exactly one red side (it doesn't necessarily have to be the same side for each).  Again use the line segment intersection algorithm.

Now for this case, draw a line segment from the green vertex that is inside of the red triangle (use the point-in-a-polygon algorithm to determine which green vertex is inside of the triangle) to each of the red triangle vertices.

[image]

**Case 5**: Green triangle overlaps red triangle, where only one side of the green triangle enter into the red triangle and where that same green side exits a different side of the red triangle.

[image]

Test for this case by checking to see that exactly one green side intersects with exactly two red sides.  Again use the line segment intersection algorithm.

Now for this case, draw a line segment from each of the intersection points (each place where a green side intersects with a red side) to each of the red vertices.  If any of these line segments basically duplicate the red edges then remove them.  If any of these new line segments cross into the green triangle then remove them (you can check for this by using the line segment intersection method against each of the green triangle's sides).  Now, test to see if any of the remaining new line segments intersect with each other; if any two do, then eliminate one, and retest until you have no more new line segments intersecting with each other.

[image: Case 5 = Solving]

And hopefully at this point you are done!

Comment: I think your approach can be generalized to work without cases, but if you're going to go by explicit cases, your might as well cover them all. You're at least missing red-inside-green, the three-line-intersection (star of David pattern), and two-green-points-inside-red.

Comment: The point in polygon test won't tell you whether the triangles are overlapping, as it's possible to overlap without the corners being in the other triangle

Comment: There are many more cases:

Star of David overlap (3 sides entering and leaving different sides).
Case 5 covers when you cover 1 corner: an additional case is needed when you cover 2.

Case 3 covers when they enter and leave the same sides. Two additional cases are needed when the two entry points are from different sides and when the two exit points are from different sides.

Case 4 covers when they enter the same side. Two additional cases are needed for when the enter different sides with either one red point covered and two red points covered

The case of red completely covered.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you can find general purpose polygon subtraction, clipping and triangulation algorithms that can be applied, but since you're limited to triangles simpler methods apply.

The basic approach is to extend the edges of the second (green) triangle, treating them as unending lines, then split the original (red) triangle up to three times, one for each green edge that intersects the red triangle, keeping the parts that are outside the red triangle. Algorithm:

```
resultSet := {}   // set of triangles
currentPoly := originalTriangle
for each edge E of secondTriangle:
    if E intersects currentPoly (*):
        Extend edge E to line L
        Split currentPoly by L into outerPoly and otherPoly (**)
        // outerPoly is on the side corresponding to the outside
        // of secondTriangle (right side if going CCW)
        resultSet += triangulatation of outerPoly (***)
        currentPoly := otherPoly
if resultSet is empty:
    resultSet := originalTriangle // no intersections
```

`(*)` A line segment intersects a polygon if the segment intersects any of the polygon edges or if it is completely contained in the polygon. For this algorithm, it is best to treat coincident lines as not intersecting (since no split will occur).

`(**)` Algorithm for splitting a convex polygon by a line

```
result := [[],[]]   // two empty lists of points
intersectionCount = 0
for each point P in the polygon:
    // each point is added to one of the result polygons
    result[intersectionCount % 2] += P
    E := edge between P and the next point Q
    if E intersects L at R:
       // each intersection point is added to both result polygons
       if R is not equal to P:
           result[intersectionCount % 2] += R
       intersectionCount += 1
       if R is not equal to Q:
           result[intersectionCount % 2] += R
```

`(***)` outerPoly will always be a triangle or quadrilateral and thus trivial to triangulate.

Answer (score 2):

The first step of this problem would be to isolate the regions of the red triangle left over after you place the green triangle over it.

Once you have these distinct shapes (in the above example, one 4 sided shape and one 3 sided shape) you will remove all shapes which are 3 sided from your "need to compute" list (as these are already triangles).

Next, you should be left with a single shape or no shapes (you can only either have 1 or two shapes after overlapping one triangle on top of another) but really, if you wanted a more general approach, you could apply this to all shapes you have left over (after triangles).  Now isolate the verticies of each shape you have and give them an order clockwise or anti-clockwise.  Start with vertex 1, then go to vertex 1+2 and attempt to draw a line to produce a triangle (check for boundary problems, such as drawing a line outside the bounds of your original triangle).  If you encounter a boundary problem, move up and try the next vertex, attempting to draw a line to vertex 1+3.  The point is you're skipping the most adjacent vertex and drawing a line to the vertex that lies immediately after that one, and then trying all verticies beyond that until you hit adjacency again.  You are constructing triangles in that case, by definition (as they have to have 3 sides using this method).

Once you produce a triangle (by successfully drawing a line from one vertex to another) re-calculate the rest of the area you must split into triangles and repeat the process, until you are left with only triangles.

Here's a (admittedly terrible) animated gif I made to show the method:
[image: Animated gif of method]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to achieve the first step?

Comment: If you have equations for the boundary lines for your triangles, you can calculate their intersection by setting them equal and solving for x and y.

Comment: "(you can only either have 1 or two shapes after overlapping one triangle on top of another)" -- If the two triangles overlap like a 'star of David' then aren't we left with three shapes?  Also, if one triangle is completely inside the other, then we can't calculate intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a stupid approach, but it's late and my brain is overloaded after 10 hours of work:

1. Merge all triangles into a polygon (with possible holes).
2. Triangulate the polygon.
3. For each resulting triangle check if it belongs **only** to the red triangle.

Example of a merged and triangulated polygon:
[image: Merged triangles]

Example when one of the triangles is completely inside another:
[image]

When triangulating, the trick would be to reuse any points from a completely enclosed triangle. You would also have a set of "hard" lines (drawn solid) which represent segments of existing triangles' sides and "soft" lines (drawn dashed) which you have to determine through triangulation.

I'm quite sure there are better ways of doing this, but there you go...

Comment: When merging, you need the difference, not the union as "merging" implies.  Otherwise if one triangle is completely inside the other, when you merge them, you just have the bigger of the two triangles.  Triangulating simply returns that big triangle, but only a portion of it is valid.

Comment: Didn't I say it was a stupid idea? :) You're right about the big triangle, I'll update the answer.